# Create loop to go down cell then repeat macro code

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I currently have a code that Saves the excel sheet in a PDF based on infomation specific to the text in cell B2, and then attach the PDF into an email and email out to the specific user.

I am unsure how to add a macro to the current code to have the cell in B2 go down the data validation list inbetted and then repeat the macro to send the next person the email specific to them.

This is the current code that I have to save pdf and then email:

```
 Sub AttachActiveSheetPDF()
 Dim IsCreated As Boolean
 Dim i As Long
 Dim PdfFile As String, Title As String
 Dim OutlApp As Object


 Title = Range("A1")

 PdfFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
 i = InStrRev(PdfFile, ".")
 If i > 1 Then PdfFile = Left(PdfFile, i - 1)
 PdfFile = Range("G5") & "_" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".pdf"

 With ActiveSheet
 .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
 End With

 On Error Resume Next
 Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
 If Err Then
 Set OutlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 IsCreated = True
 End If
 OutlApp.Visible = True
 On Error GoTo 0

 With OutlApp.CreateItem(0)

 .Subject = Title
 .To = Range("B4")
 .CC = Range("G3")
 .Body = "Hello " & Range("G5") & "," & vbLf & vbLf _
 & "Your Summary is attached. If you have any further questions about your selections, please call 1-800-XXX-XXXX." & vbLf & vbLf _
 & "Best Regards," & vbLf _
 & Application.UserName & vbLf _
 & "Implementation Specialist" & vbLf & vbLf
 .Attachments.Add PdfFile

 On Error Resume Next
 .Send
 Application.Visible = True
 If Err Then
 MsgBox "E-mail was not sent", vbExclamation
 Else
 MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", vbInformation
 End If
 On Error GoTo 0

 End With

 ' Delete PDF file
 Kill PdfFile

 ' Quit Outlook if it was created by this code
 If IsCreated Then OutlApp.Quit

 ' Release the memory of object variable
 Set OutlApp = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the data validation list? You don't give enough information to set up a pattern.

Comment: How is your data validation created? `=NamedRange` or `aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd` or something like `=$O$17:$O$18`?

Answer (score 0):

I quickly wrote an example to show how to loop through the Data Validation List.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim acell As Range, DataValCell As Range, tmpRng As Range
    Dim s As String
    Dim MyAr As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = Sheet1 '<~~> Change this to the relevant sheet

    With ws
        Set DataValCell = .Range("B2")

        '~~> Handles =NamedRange or =$O$17:$O$18
        If Left(DataValCell.Validation.Formula1, 1) = "=" Then
            s = Mid(DataValCell.Validation.Formula1, 2)
            Set tmpRng = .Range(s)
        Else '~~> Handles aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd
            s = DataValCell.Validation.Formula1
        End If

        If Not tmpRng Is Nothing Then '~~> Handles =NamedRange or =$O$17:$O$18
            For Each acell In tmpRng.Cells
                Debug.Print acell.Value
                '~~> this is where you loop through the DV List
            Next
        Else '~~> Handles aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd
            MyAr = Split(s, ",")

            For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
                Debug.Print MyAr(i)
                '~~> this is where you loop through the DV List
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The data validation is just set through the Data Validation button on the Data Tab, I have it =Sheet1!$C$2:$C$259

How would I input this code next to my email code? For example, I want to click the command button, and have it email the first person, and then go to the next person on the validation list and then email that person, and so on and so on until the list runs through it's course. I input the code above after my "End Sub" for my email code, but it is giving me an error. Can you please help with that? (I am new at VBA)